# Pass a java-script variable to .cs file

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a listview with label which displays messages from different user.I have used the table  row `<tr>` to get the id and pass it to the javascript.Now i need to pass this javascript variable to the .cs file.

```
<asp:ListView ID="msg_list" runat="server" OnItemCommand="selectedMsg" >
   <ItemTemplate>
     <table>
      <tr class="myitem" onclick=" selectedid(<%#Eval("senderId")%>) "/>
        <td>
         <asp:Label role="menuitem" ID="msg_lbl" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("msg")%>'/>
        </td>
       <tr>
     </table>

   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here's the java-script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectedid( id ) {
    alert(id);

}
</script>
```

The alert shows the selected row's id value.I need to pass this id value to .cs file.

Comment: I guess you could assign the id to Hidden Field.

Comment: If you don't want to do a form post, then Ajax?

Comment: Can you provide a sample example please.

Comment: There is a lot of [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) [available](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/basics/hello-world/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hidden field for that purpose.Looking at the code above it seems you have got your
java-script variable.Now you can pass that value to the hiddenfield and access the hiddenfield value in the .cs file.

This is how it is done.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectedid( id ) {
   var abc = id;
    document.getElementById('<%= hdn.ClientID %>').value = abc;
}
</script>
```

Now you can finally get your value in .cs file as `string mystr = hdn.value`.

Good luck